# Transparent TextBox - OnPaint not firing when changin text

Tags: winforms, graphics, textbox

My control properly starts as transparent, but once I enter text, it's going to a regular white background. If I move my mouse over the control, it fires the OnPaint again, and is able to draw the control with text correctly. How can I get it to paint the transparent background when text is being entered?

Default: [image]

Directly after entering text: [image]

After moving mouse over, to force OnPaint to fire: [image]

```
ref class CustomTextBox : System::Windows::Forms::TextBox
{
public:

    CustomTextBox()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles::SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
        SetStyle(ControlStyles::OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true); //Tried this both ways
        SetStyle(ControlStyles::AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
        SetStyle(ControlStyles::ResizeRedraw, true);
        SetStyle(ControlStyles::UserPaint, true);

        BackColor = Color::Transparent;
        ForeColor = Color::Red;
    }

    virtual void OnPrint(PaintEventArgs^ e) override
    {
        System::Windows::Forms::TextBox::OnPrint(e);
Debug::WriteLine("OnPrint: " + this->Text);
    }

    virtual void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs^ e) override
    {
        System::Windows::Forms::TextBox::OnPaintBackground(e);
Debug::WriteLine("OnPaintBackground: " + this->Text);

    }

    virtual void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs^ e) override
    {
        //System::Windows::Forms::TextBox::OnPaint(e);

        //Paint Background
        Graphics^ g = e->Graphics;
        RectangleF^ bounds = gcnew RectangleF(0, 0, Convert::ToSingle(this->Width - 1), Convert::ToSingle(this->Height - 1));
        e->Graphics->FillRectangle(gcnew SolidBrush(this->BackColor), *bounds);

        //Paint text
        g->DrawString(this->Text,this->Font,gcnew SolidBrush(Color::Red),1,1);

Debug::WriteLine("OnPaint: " + this->Text);

    }

};
```

Comment: TextBox is stone cold old, goes all the way back to Windows v1.0.  Having to run on very limited hardware back then forced them to hack it pretty badly, one crime it commits is that it paints sometimes without firing the Paint event.  Decades of app-compat prevented them from ever fixing it.  Death Star wins, you cannot make this work reliably.

Comment: Alright, what is the other options here?

Answer (score 0):

FYI - Found the solution:

1) Tie the TextChanged event to a method that will fire every time text is entered.
2) In the new method, mark the control: `control->Invalidate()` to trigger the re-painting.