# Create My Own Control

Tags: c#, visual-studio, controls

I want to create my own textbox control, which arises event when I click right button of the mouse on it. How Can I do this?

Comment: Any tutorial on the internet could get you started with this.

Comment: I can not find it, can you link it?

Comment: what search terms did you use?

Comment: for example: How create my own control and add event to it?

Comment: I am going to create a class which for example inherits from textBox class and I want to add my own event in it, so then, I will add it in visual studio toolbox

Comment: It is very simple....Create a new custom-control/user-control library project , and put your codes in there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty simple, the hard part comes in with how to raise the event:

```
public class MyMagicTextbox : TextBox
{
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> MyMagicEvent;

    protected virtual void OnMyMagicEvent(EventArgs e)
    {
        MyMagicEvent?.Invoke(this, e);
    }
}
```

It really is about that simple to inherit a textbox (or other control) and give it new methods/events. You'll have to decide on what logic raises that event and how the consuming application uses it.

---

#### Edit from comments:

> for example I want to make a textbox and define an event which arise when mouse's right button will be clicked on it..

You then have to consume (using the OnXXX event name) for the mouse click, and then raise your custom event:

```
public class MyMagicTextbox : TextBox
{
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> MyMagicEvent;

    protected virtual void OnMyMagicEvent(EventArgs e)
    {
        MyMagicEvent?.Invoke(this, e);
    }

    protected override void OnMouseClick(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
            OnMyMagicEvent(EventArgs.Empty);

        base.OnMouseClick(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am interested in the hard part, not the declaration of event...

Comment: @Beginner Given the information you gave in the question, I can't tell you any more about the "hard part". What triggers the event? What is it supposed to do? What are the event arguments? How would a consumer use it? There are a lot of holes in your question for that kind of answer.

Comment: I would add that when using visual studio, you can create a custom control by right click the project (or folder), `add --> new`, and choosing `custom control`. Then you get a control inheriting `Control` and you just need to change it to inherit whatever control you actually want to inherit.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I would not recommend doing that for inheriting TextBox, you don't need the .Designer file and when changing it to inherit from TextBox you break the designer, so double-clicking in the solution explorer will bring up an error without hand-editing the errors out of the designer file.

Comment: for example I want to make a textbox and define an event which arise when mouse's right button will be clicked on it...

Comment: Winforms TextBox is a terrible control in some ways, this is just one more way it's terrible in. If you ever tried to make it transparent, for instance, you know what I'm talking about.

Comment: @Beginner AFAIK Control have a MouseClickEvent that all controls inherit...

Comment: @Beginner I modified the answer to include how to call your custom event when the mouse right-clicks on the textbox.

Comment: @ZoharPeled If you are trying to do that level of customization to the TextBox, I agree, all Windows Forms controls pale in visual customization to WPF/UWP. If it is needed to travel down that road, go WPF, even if you have to host it in WinForms.

Comment: @Ron beyer, it's good

Comment: The reason I asked this question was that I want to modify/add the cellclick event of devexpress gridcontrol, is it possible?

Comment: @Beginner You may be able to inherit the grid control (as long as it isn't `sealed`) and add your event in much the same way, although I'm not sure how DevExpress has structured the control (if it is just one control, or a collection of "Cell" controls). I would ask a separate question about that since it is out-of-scope from this question.

Comment: I will ask another, while the downvotes do not stop me :)

Comment: Agreed. TextBox is worst then others since it doesn't go through the regular `OnPaint` all other controls do. Read Hans Passan'ts [comment about it here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43739195/transparent-textbox-onpaint-not-firing-when-changin-text)